# change table schema cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, database-schema

how do I change the schema of one of my database tables in CakePHP? The new schema will include new columns that will be added to my table and also some column name changes. I tried to do it using

```
cake schema update <mytable>
```

but I always get this error:

```
Warning: <span style="color:Red;text-align:left"><b>SQL Error:</b> 1060: Duplicate column name 'contact_id'</span> in C:\wamp\www\tests\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo_source.php on line 684
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say which database you are using so I'm assuming it's MySQL.

When I want to change a table (add or remove columns) I do it using **MySQL Query Browser** which is a desktop application that has an easy to use GUI for table editing. If for some reason you can't use that, maybe your hosting service offers a web application like **phpMyAdmin** which also allows you to edit a table without having to know too much SQL.

Once your table has the schema you want, if CakePHP seems to not realise that the table has changed go to the `app/tmp/cache` folder and delete the contents of the 3 subfolders there (but not the subfolders themselves as that sometimes causes problems).

Obviously, if your code contains references to columns that no longer exist, you will have to edit it. Otherwise everything should just work.